# i can't access my calculator object through $().click(calculator.press("") in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, events, click

I am trying to understand OOP javascript standards. I have a [codepen](http://codepen.io/rush86999/pen/QyJMPo) where I am trying to make a calculator object work and I have created multiple `$().click(calculator1.press());` code to make it. I am a newbie and dev tools says `calculator is not a function` and `object.$ is not a function`. I don't understand this error

`var calculator1 = Object.create(Calculator);
//jquery for click event to call calculator
$("#clear").click(calculator1.press("clear"));`

Comment: i am also posting jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/twpq4q8r/5/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a function as reference...but you are invoking the function instead.

Since the function you are calling requires parameters that are different than the default click handler callback you need to wrap it in an anonymous function

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
    calculator1.press("clear");// won't get invoked until event occurs
});
```

Simple example of passing function reference to click handler

```
function handler(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert(this.id);
}

$('#someID').click( handler ); // pass function name as reference, won't get invoked until event occurs
```

But you are doing:

```
$('#someID').click( handler() ); // handler() will be invoked as soon as this code line encountered
```